# Using udev to block wireless devices on Debian

Tags: linux, wifi

How to defend against Badusb devices that act as wireless non-Bluetooth devices on Debian?

I've read that the best way to block a device on Linux will be to block it using udev.

So how do I blacklist all wireless devices (non-Bluetooth that use USB adaptor) using udev?

Comment: Have you considered compiling the kernel without any USB support built in?

Comment: The kernel has no idea what device is "wireless", so it'd be pretty hard to come up with a definitive list of devices. For example; a device might be a UART Serial USB device, but have a wireless interface behind that. The kernel would have no way to distinguish between a legit UART device or one with a wireless interface behind it.